# valgrind behaves differently on mac and linux server

Tags: valgrind

When I test a program on mac and Linux server, valgrind gives different results, where valgrind on mac said there are some possibly memory leak. Could anyone explain why? Thanks a lot.

[image]
*Result from Linux server*

[image]
*Result from Mac*

Comment: You should follow the suggestion in the output that you quote for the Linux result to get more information.  Specifically, use "--leak-check=full".

Comment: If you want another vote on the Linux side to see whether the leak is real or not, try https://github.org/vmware/chap.

Comment: But why would the same code behaves differently on different servers? My friends said that it's just because valgrind on mac doesn't work perfectly. The details of valgrind on linux showed that there is no memory leak while on mac it said the memory leak happened once the program is executed.

Comment: Could be a "potential leak" in the system libraries.